# Transaction log rollback broke Log Shipping chain?

Tags: sql-server-2012, transaction-log, log-shipping

Is it correct that performing a **transaction log restore** to a previous point in time will break the log shipping chain?

If this is correct, is there a way to recover from this situation **without** having to restore a full backup and re-initialise log shipping on the 2nd server?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct that performing a transaction log restore to a previous point in time will break the log shipping chain?

Any backup restored on primary database will break logshipping and you would have to start from scratch to configure logshipping.

Comment: Even going back in time down the transactions?  Can you not apply the same process to the recovery / standby database to keep it in step?

Comment: Sorry I did not got what you are asking